# Fake mouse and keyboard input on Android

Tags: android, c++, keyboard, mouse

Is there are way to fake mouse and keyboard input on Android?

I developed an application for controlling computers with a smartphone client and since smart TVs become more interesting for people I would also be very interested in providing a server for Android.

I already discovered monkeyrunner but I'm not sure whether this is really what I want since it is a development tool. A native way would be far more attractive.

Has anyone already experimented with this? I use Qt so a C++ way would be great. I have also seen someone faking key inputs per command line is there a way to execute command line commands in an Android application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there are way to fake mouse and keyboard input on Android?

Only via custom firmware, a rooted device, or via the Android SDK tools. Apps cannot attack other apps via "fake mouse and keyboard input" for obvious security reasons.

> I have also seen someone faking key inputs per command line is there a way to execute command line commands in an Android application?

Fortunately, that will not work, unless you run as root.

Comment: Do you have any further details how a rooted device could be controlled? Its not very comfortable to do this for a user however if there is no easier way it has to be done.

Comment: @user2230199: "Do you have any further details how a rooted device could be controlled?" -- no, but there are existing apps that do this. For example, I seem to recall that there's a VNC server for Android that works if you run as root, and it should support these operations.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is an opensource project available on github which can do this there I probably can find a solution: https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server